# What is the best way to check nullable columns for differences?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL script and it needs to check values between two columns to see if the values are different. Earlier I had a simple check using `<>` but it doesn't seem to cut it when it comes to nulls.

Is the below the only way to check if the values are different?

```
declare @intValue int = 1;
declare @intNull int = 1;

select 'Values are not the same' 
where (@intNull <> @intValue) or (@intValue is null and @intNull is not null) or (@intValue is not null and @intNull is null);
```

Comment: If both values are `NULL` should they be considered the same or different?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct and, to the best of my knowledge, the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick a dummy value that you know is never used in the data:

```
coalesce(c1, -9999) <> coalesce(c2, -9999)
```

It's essentially the same as yours though a little shorter. And it might not be appropriate for all cases.

The title of your question asks for the "best" way. I was responding to the "is this the only way" question later in the body. This will save you some typing but it probably isn't wise to rely on special values like this without serious consideration.

Comment: You cannot 'know' that a specific magic number will 'never' be used.  You can make a (bad) assumption, based on specific knowledge of the current state of all things, but doing so is bad practice.

Comment: Sure you can. Perhaps you have a check constraint on that column. Or the value can only be positive. Or it's a `tinyint` and you use an out of range number for that type. Or it's a code and you know it's an invalid value. I'm not saying it's smart to rely on those kinds of things and I had already pointed out that it may not be appropriate for all cases.

Comment: User can pass `-9999`. This answer is useless.

Comment: @Bhavik It was a made up value. Practical use depends on the actual domain if the column. Ill-advised or not if you've never seen this then you haven't worked in the field very long.

Answer (score 1):

You can done with `isnull` also.

```
declare @intValue int = 1;
declare @intNull int = 1;

select 'Values are not the same' 
where (isnull(@intNull,'') <> isnull(@intValue,''))
```

Comment: This uses a magic string.  What happens when one of the values being compared is an empty string, and the other is null?  This code will say they are equal, which is entirely incorrect.

Comment: This answer is related to question not at all generic answer. For int datatype it is working fine.

Comment: You object to -9999 and then post that?!?

Comment: Just because something works doesn't make it right.  Doing this sort of thing is not, in any way, 'best'.  Also, what Shawn said.

Answer (score 1):

use `BINARY_CHECKSUM`:

```
declare @intValue int = 1;
declare @intNull int = NULL;

SELECT CAST(BINARY_CHECKSUM(@intValue) AS BIGINT)
    , CAST(BINARY_CHECKSUM(@intNull) AS BIGINT)
```

`BINARY_CHECKSUM` works on strings as well.